# Technique in which complexity of searching item doesn't depend on number of items present in list

Tags: list, time-complexity

Is there any technique in which complexity of searching an item from a list which doesn't depend on the number of items present in the list?

Comment: yes, but with limitations. hashing is one way, or full index table for small sets

Comment: I hope you did put more effort to search this information than to write this question...

Comment: Hashing or binary trees would be my favs.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is impossible. However, concerning data types with a limited range of values (e.g. usual integral data types), it can be done with a hash table.